# MS Exchange breaking inbound email DKIM by altering/adding headers

Tags: microsoft-outlook, email, exchange, dkim

I've recently been trying to implement DMARC for inbound email on our MS exchange server.
We are currently using [SpamAssassin in a Box](https://stackoverflow.com) to achieve this. Any SPF lookups seem to be working fine now, but some (not all) DKIM signature checks fail and end up in the spam inbox - I believe this is due to our Exchange server altering the DKIM signed body of the incoming mail.

Today a colleague has setup a separate VPS running Exchange server.

Just as a test, we both signed up to the same online newsletter, the newsletter email passes DKIM on his Exchange server, but seems to fail on mine.
If we compare the headers of both emails:

The last part of the headers that all-elektronics.de (Newsletter provider) sent to us (i.e. which were not added by exchange) is this Date header here, as seen from my colleague's Exchange server:
[Date header](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nHCyP.png)

However, if I look at the headers on the newsletter received on my Exchange Server, it seems to add additional headers below this Date header : [Added headers](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pfAfe.jpg)

The first thing which breaks DKIM is the fact that Exchange removes an extra blank line which was sent to us in the original email, this is from my colleagues Exchange server , notice the two "LF"s meaning two blank lines: [Blank lines](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NGpCO.jpg)

Since my Exchange server  is adding all those extra headers, it ended up removing the extra blank line when it tried to cleanup: [No blank lines](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kFU0p.jpg)

The "body" of an email, which is calculated with DKIM, starts on the first line after the first blank line of the headers. I.e., that CRLF indicated in the above screenshot denotes the "boundary" between header and body.

But in the original email they sent, before Exchange altered it, there were two blank lines. This means that the second of those two blank lines actually counts as part of the body and is taken into account when making the calculation. Exchange removing the extra one broke it

My Exchange server also seems to be changing the capitalisation of Content-Transfer-Encoding which is also breaking DKIM

Any help on this would be massively appreciated.

Comment: DKIM only cares about the header lines specified in `h=`. Most senders also use `c=relaxed/relaxed` which ignores most capitalization, and CR/LF/whitespace changes. What makes you think these are causing your DKIM failures?

Comment: I think the whitespace/capitalisation are breaking dkim based on two things:

1. When adding or removing whitespace to the body of an email I get a different DKIM hash for that email depending on the whitespaces - AFAIK this happens as the contents of the body are used when calculating the hash

2. When the Content-Transfer-Encoding header seems to get capitalised DKIM fails, but if I manually edit that header to have no caps and run it past dkimverify.exe, then DKIM passes

Comment: This link talks about the add-headers behavior: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/header-firewall-exchange-2013-help#header-firewall-on-custom-receive-connectors